# How can I write a program which can test throughput of disk?

Tags: c++, windows, file, operating-system, disk

How can I write a program which can test throughput of disk in Windows systems using c++?

What's the mainly steps and APIs that I can use to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One open-source benchmark is [bonnie](http://www.textuality.com/bonnie/), which mostly uses the standard C API. You'll need to change some of the timing functions to suit Windows.

Comment: Hi Pete,"I believe that
memory is in short supply, so caches max out, thus
many I/O operations end up really doing I/O"what does this sentence mean in the bonnie website?

Comment: If you have a a 1TB database on a machine with 16GB RAM, what's going to matter is how fast the disk can seek/read rather than how good the OS is at caching, because the caches will get exhausted quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In outline:

- write a known (large) amount of data to disk ( see write() )
- start clock (see time() or clock() )
- read data from disk   (see read() )
- stop clock (see above)
- report results (see cout)